MaterialAlertDialog with border
We are switching to Material 3 and I'm trying to create a MaterialAlertDialog with a stroke (border). I've tried a lot of different things and read a lot of different articles, but I don't get the desired result.
What we want to achieve:

The best result so far is:

I don't know why the "android:background" is applied to every component separately.
Here is the theme and the styles we are using:
<style name="App_Theme" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>


<style name="AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_dialog_background</item>
</style>

shape_dialog_background.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/colorDialogBackground" />
    <corners android:radius="28dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/colorDialogStroke" />
</shape>

And the dialog itself is created like this:
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(Activity.this)
   .setTitle(R.string.title)
   .setMessage(R.string.description)
   .setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel, dialogClickListener)
   .setNegativeButton(R.string.discard, dialogClickListener)
   .show();

What am I missing here?
Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks!
--------- UPDATE ---------
I've managed to achieve the needed result by removing
@drawable/shape_dialog_background
from the style and creating the dialog like this:
AlertDialog dialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(Activity.this)
   .setTitle(R.string.title)
   .setMessage(R.string.description)
   .setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel, dialogClickListener)
   .setNegativeButton(R.string.discard, dialogClickListener)
   .create();

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.shape_dialog_background);
dialog.show();

But is there a way to do it in the theme, so the same style applies to all dialogs by default?
